# The application will need to have the ability to work off line for later upload via WiFi or cellular connection

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I am working on an application where i need to upload the data to the server for that i need to check the network connection(wifi/3G) if network is not there it will store somewhere till the network available one  network find it automatically upload to the server.I don't have any concept to work on this type of situation..Can anyone tell me how to work ...

Comment: what kind of data you want to upload?

Comment: i need to upload images and text data both to upload to the website

Comment: well, you should check the Reachability as @whiteagle mentioned. Copy data to Documents folder and try to upload when network is up. I would use AFNetworking to upload files.

Comment: i have one doubt as well suppose i have saved somewhere and set timer to check the network connection after some interval once it will find network connection it will upload but suppose in this duration user restart phone now how it will upload...

Comment: Reachability has callback for it, if network appears

Comment: It will work if the application shut down due to some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/index.html) framework to detect the connection type. Wrap it to some background loop to check and you're done.

Comment: I know Reachability we use to check the network connection suppose while uploading i don't have network connection then it should store it automatically to cache and need to check connection continuously once it will available it should upload automatically....

Comment: If you have small size data you can use CoreData as storage

Comment: unless you provide more details on what exactly you're going to upload and how, I doubt anybody can answer this. One approach would be to store the data somewhere and then post it to the server with NSUrlConnection, but it does depends on what you're going to post. The key here is to have some background thread which will continuously check for connection availability and do the job when proceeds.

Comment: @whiteagle would you please help to find what happened if user restart phone while checking the connection availability and how to upload data in this situation...

Comment: use some flag in NSUserDefaults which will be ok only when the data is uploaded successfully. Put some timestamp there or something to differentiate the latest uploaded version. Of course you might use the local DB for that, but it would be an overkill in such situation.